# getting the sci-hub url using the file title/URL

Tags: scraping, url

I have a .txt file that contains a list of 854 articles urls and titles (from the different journals and onferences sites). I want to have the list of sci-hub urls of thesse files. is there possible?

I'am working on windows. any suggestion for any library language or tooln especially the free or open sources ones

my txt files looks like this :
the titles file;

> Association between C-reactive protein and type 2 diabetes in a
>    Tunisian population
>   Association between CTLA-4 gene promoter (49 A/G) in exon 1 polymorphisms 
>   population  Association between RANTES polymorphisms and asthma severity

the URL file

> www.apps.who.int/iris/handle/10665/117788
>   www.ar.iiarjournals.org/content/35/3/1763.short
>   www.archive.unu.edu/unupress/food2/UID10E/UID10E1G.HTM

I want to gave something like this:

> www.sci-hub/xxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> www.sci-hub/xxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> www.sci-hub/xxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: Are you looking for an app or a library? For what OS or language? What is your price limit if it comes to paid solutions?

Comment: Also, could you please post at least a sample of your .TXT file, to give us a better idea of how to help you?

Comment: @Mawg updated the question

Comment: Is it two files, for title & url, or one combined file? If one, what's the format? If two, how to link them? e.g line X of titles is associated with line X or URLs? Also, can you code, or must we provide a tool? If you can code, Python is an easy language - take a look at https://pypi.org/project/scihub/   Also, take a look at https://www.ibtimes.co.uk/sci-hub-pirate-bay-scientists-now-available-anonymous-telegram-messaging-app-1560576

Comment: my question is how to have the sci-hub urls using either the titles or the url files. the files are in .txt format. I'am searching for any tool or package to do so.